# Android Material Stepper Showing Empty View After Navigating Back To The View

Tags: android, androidx, navigationcontroller, mat-stepper

i am using Android Material Stepper Library which is working fine for the first time initialization in fragment but when i come back to the fragment it is showing empty view i have tried everything tried to release stepper layout remove all views and everything else i could but still same response

```
  private void initStepper2() {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "initStepper", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        mStepperLayout = mainView.findViewById(R.id.stepperLayout);
        mStepperLayout.setSaveEnabled(false);


        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                stepArrayList.clear();
                stepArrayList.add(new FirstStepFragment());

                stepArrayList.add(new ThirdStepFragment());


                stepperAdapter = new StepperAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), getActivity(), stepArrayList);
                mStepperLayout.setAdapter(stepperAdapter);

                mStepperLayout.requestLayout();
                mStepperLayout.refreshDrawableState();
                stepperAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }, 300);
    }
```

this is where i am initializing stepper

```
 @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "OnDetach", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//        mStepperLayout.removeAllViews();
//        mStepperLayout.removeAllViewsInLayout();
//        mStepperLayout.refreshDrawableState();
//        mStepperLayout.requestLayout();
//        mStepperLayout.setAdapter(null);

        super.onDetach();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onDestroyView", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//        mStepperLayout.removeAllViews();
//        mStepperLayout.removeAllViewsInLayout();
//        mStepperLayout.refreshDrawableState();
//        mStepperLayout.requestLayout();
//        mStepperLayout.setAdapter(null);
        super.onDestroyView();

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onPause", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//        mStepperLayout.removeAllViews();
//        mStepperLayout.removeAllViewsInLayout();
//        mStepperLayout.refreshDrawableState();
//        mStepperLayout.requestLayout();
//        mStepperLayout.setAdapter(null);
        super.onPause();
    }
```

i have tried all of these but still not getting it

[image]

this is what i am getting for the first time when initializing fragment

[image]

and this is the second time when i re-navigate to the fragment

```
 mainView.findViewById(R.id.L1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                navController = Navigation.findNavController(mainView);
                navController.navigate(R.id.action_newComplaintFragment_to_registerNCFragment);
            }
        });
```

this is how i am navigating to the fragment using android x navigation controller via navigation map

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the wrong `FragmentManager` here:

```
stepperAdapter = new StepperAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), getActivity(), stepArrayList);
```

Whenever your fragment is fully container within another (such as your `mStepperLayout` being part of your `NewComplainFragment`), you need to use the `childFragmentManager` and **not** the Activity's FragmentManager:

```
stepperAdapter = new StepperAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), getActivity(), stepArrayList);
```

Comment: Great! If this answered your question, make sure to hit the checkmark by the answer to accept the answer and remove the question from the list of unanswered questions. Best of luck going forward!